# Get details and/or preview pane similar to Windows

Tags: windows, 15.10

Is it possible to get a side preview pane and/or details pane in Ubuntu?

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "side preview pane"? Can you provide a screenshot or a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Please see the edited question. And sorry if you don't like the image.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html

Answer (score 4):

[Gloobus preview](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html) does that and [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/gloobus-preview-update-brings-gtk3-and.html) has 2 articles on that (2nd link also has a video). From the 1st link:

Install the PPA ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview
```

And a previewer:

Nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get install gloobus-sushi
nautilus -q
```

Nemo:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-gloobus-sushi
nemo -q
```

Press a space after selecting a file to preview it (and another space to remove the preview). Example image:

[image]

Only works for files smaller than 10Mb.

Comment: Is it possible to configure for details pane also and select to show anyone of them?